# How do I pass year month and date in a function to created related directory?

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
def author_document_path(instance, filename):
    return f"documents/{ instance.author.username }/%y/%m/%d/{filename}"


def author_blog_images(instance, filename):
    return f"blog-images/{instance.author.username}/%y/%m/%d/{filename}"

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # other fields
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=author_blog_images)
    documents = models.FileField(upload_to=author_document_path)
```

What is the right way of passing `f"blog-images/{instance.author.username}/%y/%m/%d/{filename}"` in above two functions because these functions doesn't create year folders as 2019, month folder as 5 and day folder as 30. The directories look like this after uploading respected files and images:

[image]

this is not what I want I want it to look like:

[image]

Can you help me with this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first fetch the current day, and then you can obtain the `year`, `month` and `day` attribute, like:

```
from datetime import date

def author_blog_images(instance, filename):
    td = date.today()
    return f'blog-images/{instance.author.username}/{td.year}/{td.month}/{td.day}/{filename}'
```

Here `td.month` and `td.day` will *not* have leading zeros (so it will be printed as `2019/5/30`, *not* `2019/05/30`). You can however use leading zeros in the format string, like:

```
from datetime import date

def author_blog_images(instance, filename):
    td = date.today()
    return f'blog-images/{instance.author.username}/{td.year}/{td.month:02d}/{td.day:02d}/{filename}'
```

or we can use a specific date formatting:

```
from datetime import date

def author_blog_images(instance, filename):
    td = date.today().strftime('%y/%b/%d')
    return f'blog-images/{instance.author.username}/{td}/{filename}'
```

We can also use, like [@BearBrown says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379452/how-do-i-pass-year-month-and-date-in-a-function-to-created-related-directory/56379484#comment99359345_56379484), Django's [**`timezone.now`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now):

```
from django.utils import timezone

def author_blog_images(instance, filename):
    td = timezone.now().strftime('%y/%b/%d')
    return f'blog-images/{instance.author.username}/{td}/{filename}'
```

we can even pas an *f-string* as parameter to `strftime`, like [@chepner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379452/how-do-i-pass-year-month-and-date-in-a-function-to-created-related-directory/56379484#comment99359470_56379484) to replace certain parts of the before, and then let the `strftime` format the `time` with the format string produced by the f-string:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def author_blog_images(instance, filename):
    return timezone.now().strftime(f'blog-images/{instance.author.username}/%y/%b/%d/{filename}')
```

There is however an edge case that should be taken into account here: if the `instance.author.username`, or the `filename` contains formatting parts like `%d` and `%b`, then the `strftime` will replace these with the day/month/... respectively. Although that is not very common, it is something to take into account.

Another thing that you should take into account is that when the `author` changes, or its `username`, the file will *not* be renamed, so it will still hold the name of the old author (or the old username of that author).

Comment: maybe better django.utils.timezone https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now ?

Comment: Note that `strftime` can create the entire path: `date.today().strftime(f'blog-images/{instance.author.username}/%y/%b/%d/{filename}')`

Comment: @chepner: there is one possible problem here I think: if the `usename` or `filename` contains a `%d` for example. I agree that that is not very common, I will add it to the answer, but I think in a limited number of cases, it might fail.

Comment: Ah, good point. `strftime` should be limited to fixed strings.